# Reload data into UIPickerView

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

i need to refresh the data in the UIPickerView.
i'm using

```
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

but my problem is that i need to reset the selected row as well, i want the selected row to go back to index 0, at the moment it is staying at the same index as it was before calling the reloadAllComponents function

can anyone help please??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

should do it